# WordPress - edit page and edit post pages looks weird

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have fresh install wordpress latest version 4.7.3.

Now when I go to edit any post or page(I have not added mine.I edited default - sample page), the edit page looks weird. I think CSS is not loading correctly.

I'm new to wordpress. For more understanding I've attached screenshots also.
[Edit page coming after clicking on edit][1]

Comment: Where is your screenshot?

Comment: just added screenshots.

Comment: Did you check your console for any errors?

Comment: Browser console - No error.

Comment: and also no any error in PHP or server error log.

Comment: Might want to import the theme again.

Comment: But it is fresh install and using default theme.

Comment: @prafull-patel-satasiya Try to deactivate the theme, then re-activated, the problem will fix. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Prabu
Still no success.
I have deleted installed wordpress and reinstalled now.
but the same issue is there.This problem is in other theme also.
I think there might be a file permission issue.

Comment: @prafull-patel-satasiya Have you checked folder permission on theme folder?

Comment: @Prabu,
wp-content/themes folder have 0755 and all the folder inside this folder has 0755 and all the files have 0644.

Comment: @prafull-patel-satasiya There is no problem with your file permissions? Need to check any plugins conflict happen? Have you got any error in firebug console?

Comment: But it is fresh install. I have not done anything.Even I have not added page, post or theme.I have just completed installation and went to edit post. Is there any possibility of wordpress bug in latest version?
No error in firebug.

Comment: @Prabu,

I have installed same on localhost then it is working fine but what I have figured out is:

when I have seen in console in browser, I can see that in <head> one css is included and it's path is 

http://blog.specscale.com/wp-admin/A.load-styles.php,qc=1,adir=ltr,aload,P5B,P5D=dashicons,,admin-bar,,buttons,,media-views,,common,,forms,,admin-menu,,dashboard,,list-tables,,edit,,revisions,,media,,themes,,about,,nav-menu,aload,P5B,P5D=s,,widgets,,site-icon,,l10n,,wp-auth-check,aver=4.7.3.pagespeed.cf.P-OO66YthQ.css. and this path is not available on server.

Comment: My site is hosted on blog.specscale.com.When I changes above path to http://specscale.com/blog/wp-admin/A.load-styles.php,qc=1,adir=ltr,aload,P5B,P5D=dashicons,,admin-bar,,buttons,,media-views,,common,,forms,,admin-menu,,dashboard,,list-tables,,edit,,revisions,,media,,themes,,about,,nav-menu,aload,P5B,P5D=s,,widgets,,site-icon,,l10n,,wp-auth-check,aver=4.7.3.pagespeed.cf.P-OO66YthQ.css

it is working fine.